# OpenCV find contours of separate objects

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Original binary image

[image: 1]

Find contours result

[image: 2]

I'm dealing with images like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnrAd.png). There is some small connection between squares as you can see, currently I'm directly applying cv2.findContours on the image and the result is connected squares are detected as a big object while I want them to be separated. Can someone help me to get this work?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to solve this issue by applying morphological transformations + watershed transformation on your source image.

Segmenting connected contours is a quite common use-case, you can find a tutorial for a similar problem in the OpenCV documentation:

https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html